# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyNote when working with mpirun

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

After installing QUANTUM ESPRESSO on a i7-laptop I tried to do a scf calculation to see if the QUANTUM ESPRESSO works. I got an output, and the results seems to be OK. However, there is an error that appears in the terminal. It is annoying that it will appear in every calculation I do and also I don`t know if that error affects my calculations. The error appears like that

````
/Desktop/folder$ mpirun '/homeDesktop/qe-7.0/bin/pw.x' -in scf.in> scf.out```
    ```Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyNote: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL```
    ```Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
    Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL
````

Can anyone help me to fix this, please?

Comment: Did you compiled QE for running in parallel?

Comment: After installing Quantum Espresso I installed mpi to be able to work in parallel environment . To install the mpi I used the command :                                                                            
 `sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev`

Comment: This is problem of display driver in newer version of ubuntu. either switch to gdm3 or just ignore the error and keep working

Comment: I`m using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these messages are anything to worry about as far as running a MPI parallel version of Quantum Espresso are concerned.

`Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key` is to do with X permissions, and has been reported elsewhere, https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/njfvoq/invalid_mitmagiccookie1_key_when_running_mpi/ for example, when using openMPI and certain flavours of Linux, mostly more modern versions of Ubuntu and variants thereon. Ignore it.

`Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_DENORMAL` is telling you that your calculation produced some sub/[denormal](https://denormal) numbers. This is typical and almost certainly harmless. Ignore it.